# Android VideoView playing video from url file extension required?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I am using VideoView to display video from url. Does this url need to have file extension. like,

```
http://www.somedomain.com/samplevideo.mp4
```

I have url like this,

```
http://www.somedomain.com/samplevideo
```

And it is saying can't play the video. Any suggestions ?

My code is as below :

```
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    waitSign = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    waitSign.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    MediaController contorls = new MediaController(this);
    contorls.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(contorls);
    String url = "http://www.somedomain.com/samplevideo";
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
    videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys no satisfactory answers yet hence, I tried with url,

```
http://www.somedomain.com/samplevideo
```

But shows can't play the video, then I tried this url,

```
 http://www.somedomain.com/samplevideo.mp4
```

Surprisingly url with file extension worked very well.

So I think the file extension must be required.

Answer (score 0):

even though the video is of .mp4 format, videoview can only play videos if their encoding is in `**H.264**`
**that means the codac format must be in H.265 HEVC or H.264 AVC or H.263**
check it out here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html